# Animated chart with python plotly without "play" button

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm new to python and dash and trying to make an animated chart. I have a graph object scatter and it is animated. It works by clicking on the "play" button as shown in many examples. But is there a way to start animation without a button, e.g. some autoplay property?
Here is example of my figure:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go

df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,49),columns=['x','y'])
df['x']=['00:00', '00:30', '01:00', '01:30', '02:00', '02:30', '03:00', '03:30', '04:00', '04:30', '05:00', '05:30', '06:00', '06:30', '07:00', '07:30', '08:00', '08:30','09:00', '09:30',
                                          '10:00', '10:30', '11:00', '11:30', '12:00', '12:30', '13:00', '13:30', '14:00', '14:30', '15:00', '15:30', '16:00', '16:30', '17:00', '17:30', '18:00', '18:30','19:00', '19:30',
                                          '20:00', '20:30', '21:00', '21:30', '22:00', '22:30', '23:00', '23:30', '24:00']
df['y']=[396, 365, 317, 415, 495, 353, 493, 413, 472, 335, 305, 465, 425, 401, 466, 476, 400, 473, 365, 406, 345, 439, 325, 367, 445, 478, 406, 469, 384, 468, 370, 328, 445, 376, 355, 377, 
                                          361, 324, 426, 413, 454, 479, 324, 498, 386, 438, 330, 309, 424]

fig1Slide1 = go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter(x=df['x'][:0], 
                                       y=df['y'][:0],
                                       mode='lines',
                                       line = dict(color='rgb(214,40,40)',width=1),
                                       fill='tozeroy',
                                       fillcolor='rgba(236,156,156,0.5)')])
fig1Slide1.update(frames=[go.Frame(data=[
            go.Scatter(x=df['x'][:k], 
                       y=df['y'][:k])])for k in range(0,49)])
fig1Slide1.update_layout(updatemenus=[dict(type="buttons", buttons=[dict(label="Play",method="animate",args=[None, {"frame": {"duration": 30}}])])] )

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(figure=fig1Slide1)
    ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: did you check in documentation if it doesn't have option `autoplay` or `autostart` ?

Comment: Hi Rezer : consider providing reproducible examples! I guessed the import you didn't reproduce on top of your snippet. But then, when executing, nothing happens. Could you complete your example to make it runnable ?

Comment: it would be easier if you create minimal working code which we could simply copy and run.

Comment: I updated my code example to run it in dash

Comment: meanwhile I created working code - I found only `dcc.Graph(..., animate=True,  animation_options={"frame": {"duration": 30}})` which doesn't give error but it also doesn't start animation on my computer.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but it doesn't start animation too

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id="my-graph", figure=fig1Slide1),
    dcc.Interval(id='interval', interval=1000, max_intervals=1),
    html.Div(id="dummy-output")
])

app.clientside_callback(
    """
    function(figure) {
        Plotly.animate(document.querySelector('.js-plotly-plot'))
    }
    """,
    Output('dummy-output', 'children'),
    Input('interval', 'n_intervals'),
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
```

The idea is to use a [clientside callback](https://dash.plotly.com/clientside-callbacks) so we can call plotlyjs's `animate` function on the plot. Since you've already set the frames on your figure we don't need to pass them to `animate`. We only need to pass a dom element or id referring to the figure.

https://plotly.com/javascript/animations/

An interval with `max_intervals=1` is used as an `Input` so the callback runs only once after a second (`interval=1000`).

https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/interval